# Title formatting with graphics

Tags: formatting, titlesec, multicol

I am trying to achieve this look for my chapter titles:

[image: Desired look]

To achieve this formatting I use **titlesec** package like this :

```
\titleformat{name=\chapter}[hang]
        {\LARGE\sffamily\raggedright}{\includegraphics[height=5em]{chapter.png} 
\large{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}}{0em}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0.5em}{2em}
```

and so far it looks like this :
[image: My current look]

Could you please help me how to achieve this ? I tried to experiment with multicols but it didn't work. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I optained better results *without* using `titlesec` (IMO it can't handle this particular situation, because you need to restyle the complete arrangement of the elements constituting the title) and hope that you like it though.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
  \vspace*{35\p@}
  \begingroup\parindent \z@ 
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \parbox{0.33\textwidth}{\rule{0.3\textwidth}{0.3\textwidth}}
      %replace \rule in the line above with \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth{chapter.png} 
      \parbox{0.66\textwidth}{%
      \raggedright \sffamily%or whatever the font is
      \if@mainmatter
        \LARGE \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 5\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak}
  \vskip 30\p@
  \endgroup
}

\c@chapter=6%only to reproduce your example
\makeatother

%Test
\begin{document}
\chapter{Properties of Stock Option Prices}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I just found out that I haven't responded. Sorry. At the time I think I was waiting for more accurate answer, then gave up and probably forgot about it. Thanks for answer, however :)